# Matplotlib skip color for assigned interval in map plotted from GeoPandas DataFrame, if attribute don't have value in range of user defined bins

Tags: python, geopandas, legend, mapping, matplotlib

I have a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame which I am plotting against a specific column and the colour of the output/map is same for different assigned bins/intervals.
The issue is because, sometimes, there is no value in/between the range assigned in the user defined scheme for the column/variable which we are plotting, like here

I have given 4 ranges

```
0 - 0.25,  
0.25 - 0.50,  
0.50 - 0.75,  
0.75 - 1.00
```

but the variable/column from dataframe which I am plotting does not have any value in the range `0.75 - 1.00`.

So it is assigning the same colour to the legend of  the intervals `0.50 - 0.75`, `0.75 - 1.00`,

[image: same colour legend]

But I want to keep the bins values and legends static, as if, it should show the legends of 4 different colours only,

[image: all legends]

and it should ideally skip that interval/colour while plotting inside the polygons of the map if there is no value in that interval/range,

and it should still shows that interval/range in the legend.

Like, if here, there was no value between `0.75` to `1.00`, then it may skip the green colour from the listed colour map assigned for that specific bound to plot inside the polygons,

but still shows that range/interval in the legend.

```
cmap = ListedColormap(["red", "orange", "blue", "green"])

classification_kwds={'bins':[0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]}
```

Also, if you will see the script, and look closely at the legends of 1st figure in my question, the color sequence which I have given in cmap = is in the order "red", "orange", "blue", "green",

but when the value in range (0.75 - 1.00) is missing, it is skipping the orange color and jumping to the blue (3rd color in the sequence) instead of picking the orange (2nd color in the sequence), i.e., not following a proper trend.

Is there any way possible?

```
for day in days_list:
    map_attribute = "far"
    df2 = csv_file[["state_id", "state_name", map_attribute]].loc[csv_file["days"] == day]
    new_df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'state_id', how="left")
    new_df.drop(columns=['state_name_y'], inplace = True)
    new_df.rename(columns={"state_name_x": "state_name"}, inplace = True)
    df_new = new_df.replace(np.nan,0)
    
    cmap = ListedColormap(["red", "orange", "blue", "green"])
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
    
    df_new.plot(
    ax=ax,
    column=map_attribute,
    linewidth=1,
    cmap=cmap,
    scheme='User_Defined',
    edgecolor='black',
    alpha=0.9,
    classification_kwds={'bins':[0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1.00]},
    legend=True
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove the last value (`1.00`) in `bins` list. Then the last legend item disappears. If it doesn't, it means that there is at least one item in range `(0.75 - 1.00)`.

```
classification_kwds = {'bins':[0.25, 0.50, 0.75]}
```

For example, column `VALUE` range is `1 - 764` in my data. When I use `classification_kwds={'bins':[20, 50, 764, 1000]}`, the result is:

[image]

When I remove the last value, the result is:

[image]

Comment: Hiii @kadir, thanks for the time, but what I meant by keeping the bin values and legends static was that, I want to keep the bin values same coz I have a large dataset and I want to iterate the same bin values over that dataset for generating map. Some of those datasets might not be having values in the range of specific bin interval, so I just want that matplotlib somehow skip that specific colour to fill in the polygon.

Comment: Legends are not an issue, they can be added separately, but if you look closely at the figures in my question, the colour sequence which I have given in cmap =  is in the order "red", "orange", "blue", "green", but when the value in range (0.75 - 1.00) is missing, it is skipping the orange colour and jumping to the blue (3rd colour in the sequence) instead of picking the orange (2nd colour in the issue) in 1st figure, else colour fills won’t be a problem if it already picked the proper colour in sequence for the lower and upper bounds.

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan I noticed that. But I couldn't understand the reason of  skipping the colors.

Comment: skipping like, in the 1st figure kindly see that, when when there is no value in the last range which is 4th interval here (0.75 - 1.00): for which green color is assigned, it should not pick the green color to fill in polygons, rather it should have taken the first 3 colors for the respective intervals, i.e red", "orange" and "blue" @kadir

Comment: When I run the script it skipped one of the middle colors (for example, in this case orange). I didn't figure it out why. Therefore I added the result with three colors in `cmap`

Comment: If it would fill colour in sequence, then it will be easy to handle the outliers like at lower end or upper end, coz generally the values are missing from either 1st class or last class of the assigned interval. But here the colour of middle ranges are not getting filled, which is causing hassle.